# CE Cache Escape tags being ignored

Tags: ce-cache

This is a cross-post from the Devot:ee forums.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-cache/viewthread/9173

I’m hoping I’m missing something simple.
My `{exp:ce_cache:escape}` tag pair simply seems to be ignored.

Templates aren’t unusual.

```
{exp:ce_cache:it}
  {exp:ce_cache:escape}
    {current_time format="%g:%i:%s"}
  {/exp:ce_cache:escape}
{/exp:ce_cache:it}
```

The time never changes.
When I look at the cached file through the CP, it shows the cached time, not the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping will escape pretty much everything it can with {exp..} tags and later in the [parse order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf). If you would like to escape things with an early parse order too, like global variables, you'll want to use pre escaping. Here's an explanation from the [Pre Escaping documentation](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-cache/user-guide/tags#pre-escaping).

> If the Escape tag is given a unique tagpart (example: `{exp:ce_cache:escape:blah}…{/exp:ce_cache:escape:blah}` has a unique tagpart of `blah`) then its tagdata will be pre-escaped (escaped even before segment variables and globals are parsed) when using EE 2.4.0+.

I hope that helps. :)

**Edit**

Here's a quick example:

```
{exp:ce_cache:it}
   <p>This should be cached: {current_time}</p>

   {exp:ce_cache:escape:pre}
      <p>This should not be cached: {current_time}</p>
   {/exp:ce_cache:escape:pre}
{/exp:ce_cache:it}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of CE Cache.

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to pre-escape within a snippet. 1.9.4 beta supports this. Thanks!